# ajax - sending data as json to php server and receiving response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to grasp more than I should at once.

Let's say I have 2 inputs and a button, and on button click I want to create a json containing the data from those inputs and send it to the server.

I think this should do it, but I might be wrong as I've seen a lot of different (poorly explained) methods of doing something similar.

```
    var Item = function(First, Second) {
        return {
            FirstPart : First.val(), 
            SecondPart : Second.val(), 
        };
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send_item").click(function() {
            var form = $("#add_item");

            if (form) {
                item = Item($("#first"), $("#second"));

                $.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "post.php", 
                    data: { 'test' : item },
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

In PHP I have

```
class ClientData
{
    public $First;
    public $Second;

    public function __construct($F, $S)
    {
        $this->First = F;
        $this->Second = S;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['test']))
{
    // do stuff, get an object of type ClientData
}
```

The problem is that $_POST['test'] appears to be an array (if I pass it to json_decode I get an error that says it is an array and if I iterate it using foreach I get the values that I expect to see).
Is that ajax call correct? Is there something else I should do in the PHP bit?

Comment: You also need to fix ``$this->First = F;`` (no dollar sign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending raw `form` data:
js part:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php", 
    data: item ,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

php part:

```
..
if (isset($_POST['FirstPart']) && isset($_POST['SecondPart']))
{
    $fpart = $_POST['FirstPart'];
    $spart = $_POST['SecondPart'];
    $obj = new ClientData($fpart, $spart);
}
...
```

---

For sending `json` string:
js part:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php", 
    data: {'test': JSON.stringify(item)},
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

php part:

```
..

if (isset($_POST['test']))
{
    $json_data = $_POST['test'];
    $json_arr = json_decode($json_data, true);
    $fpart = $json_arr['FirstPart'];
    $spart = $json_arr['SecondPart'];
    $obj = new ClientData($fpart, $spart);
}
...
```

Comment: I don't think this is ok. Imagine one json for an object that has 20 fields. + Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Comment: The way I'm creating item is correct? I keep getting "undefined string offset" for the updated version.

Comment: it usually returns the offset name in error, like `Illegal string offset 'host'`, what name is in error?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a content type of json and use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to format the data payload.

```
$.ajax ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "post.php", 
   data: JSON.stringify({ test: item }),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 100%. In my example test is a string. Here it is a variable? Holding... ? EDIT: oh, I think I get it...

Comment: I realized I should use contentType, not data type.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: But I still can't access it from php. isset($_POST['test']) returns false.

Comment: check your browser dev tool (F12) to inspect the POST payload.  do you see 'test' there?

Answer (score 1):

When sending an AJAX request you need to send valid JSON. You can send an array, but you need form valid JSON before you send your data to the server. So in your JavaScript code form valid JSON and send that data to your endpoint.

In your case the `test` key holds a `value` containing a JavaScript object with two attributes. JSON is **key value** coding in string format, your PHP script does not not how to handle JavaScript (jQuery) objects.

https://jsfiddle.net/s1hkkws1/15/

This should help out.

Answer (score -1):

Try send in ajax:

```
data: { 'test': JSON.stringify(item) },
```

instead:

```
data: { 'test' : item },
```

Comment: in this case how should I get the data? $_POST['item'] doesn't really work.

Comment: Ah, so try like @devlin wrote.
in ajax:
data: { test: JSON.stringify(item) },
In php you receive json, then you should parse only

Comment: no, you want to stringify the whole data payload, not just 'item'.